# Implicit conversion to template

Tags: c++, casting, overloading, implicit-conversion

My example below suggests that implicit conversions from non-template types to template types won't work as seamlessly as those only involving non-template types. Is there a way to make them work nonetheless?

Example:

```
struct point;

template<unsigned d> struct vec {
  vec() { }
  // ...
};

template<> struct vec<2> {
  vec() { }
  vec(const point& p) { /* ... */ } // Conversion constructor
  // ...
};

struct point {
  operator vec<2>() { return vec<2>(/* ... */); } // Conversion operator
};

template<unsigned d> vec<d> foo(vec<d> a, vec<d> b) {
  return vec<d>(/* ... */);
}

template<unsigned d1, unsigned d2>
vec<d1 + d2> bar(vec<d1> a, vec<d2> b) {
  return vec<d1 + d2>(/* ... */);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  point p1, p2;
  vec<2> v2;
  vec<3> v3;
  foo(v2, p1);
  foo(p2, v2);
  foo(p1, p2);
  bar(v3, p1);
}
```

**Is there a way to let this code auto-convert from `point` to `vec<2>`?**

I know I can overload `foo` and `bar` to allow for `point` arguments, delegating to the `vec` implementation using an explicit conversion. But doing this for all parameter combinations will become tedious, particularly for functions with many such parameters. So I'm not interested in solutions where I have to duplicate code for every parameter combination of every function.

It appears that neither the conversion constructor nor the cast operator are sufficient to achieve this. At least my gcc 4.7.1 reports `no matching function call`, although it does name the desired function in a notice, stating that `‘point’ is not derived from ‘vec<d>’`.

Comment: Which line is giving that error?  Also, `unsigned` is not a C++ type.

Comment: @James: The errors are reported for the lines with the function invocations, although the notices mention various other lines as well. Feel free to copy&compile the code above, as it is self-contained. Section 3.9.1 of [the C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) names `unsigned`, so why would that not be a C++ type, shared with C?

Comment: No, it declares `unsigned char`, `unsigned short int`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int`, and `unsigned long long int` as unsigned integer types.

Comment: But I digress.  :)  In theory it should be sufficient to just provide the conversion operator.  You have circular references between `vec` and `point` as it currently stands, and that might be causing the compiler to get confused.

Comment: The only variant I could force it to work is to call `foo<2>( v2, p1 )`. BTW, there's no need to add `operator vec<2>()` to `point`

Comment: @borisbn: interesting approach, but in my real application many of the functions will be operators, for which naming a template argument won't work at all.

Comment: I think, I ran before the horse. Look at @jogojapan 's answer

Comment: @James This is not true. `unsigned`, `long` and `short` type specifiers are explicitly mentioned as _simple type specifiers_ that can be used to fully name a type. There is a nice table in **7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]** describing these types.

Comment: @Fiktik Ah, I stand corrected, and slightly disgusted.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the conversion from `point` to `vec<2>`, because at the time when the function call `foo(v1,p1)` is processed, a function `foo` that expects a `vec<2>` as second argument does not exist yet. It's just a function template, and in order for this to be instantiated to a `foo(const vec<2> &,const vec<2> &)`, a function call with these exact argument types would have to be given.

In order for the code to work, the compiler would have to guess *both* how to instantiate the template parameters, *and* what type the `point` argument to convert to. This is too much in the general case (although in your particular code it appears simple, because there is no other possible way to interpret the intent of the programmer).

In terms of solving this, the only thing I can think of is to create highly templated conversion functions:

```
template <typename T>
struct make_vec
{ };

template <unsigned d>
struct make_vec<vec<d>>
{
  static constexpr unsigned dim = d;
  using type = vec<dim>;

  static const type &from(const type &v)
  { return v; }
};

template <>
struct make_vec<point>
{
  static constexpr unsigned dim = 2;
  using type = vec<dim>;

  static type from(const point &p)
  { return type(p); }
};

template <typename T>
typename make_vec<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type make_vec_from(T&& arg)
{ return make_vec<typename std::decay<T>::type>::from(std::forward<T>(arg)); }
```

And then implement the `foo` and `bar` functions as general templates (accepting all kinds of types, not only `vec<d>`, using `make_vec` defined above to convert the given types to the right kind of `vec<d>`):

```
namespace detail {
  /* Your original implementation of foo. */
  template<unsigned d> vec<d> foo(vec<d>, vec<d>) {
    return vec<d>(/* ... */);
  }
}

/* Templated version of foo that calls the conversion functions (which do
   nothing if the argument is already a vec<d>), and then calls the
   foo() function defined above. */
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
typename make_vec<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type foo(T&& arg, Ts&&... args)
{ return detail::foo(make_vec_from(arg),make_vec_from(args)...); }
```

In the case of `bar` you also need a way to calculate the return type, which is `vec<d1+d2+d3...>`. For this, a sum calculator is required, also templated:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct dsum {
  static constexpr unsigned value = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct dsum<T,Ts...> {
  static constexpr unsigned value = make_vec<typename std::decay<T>::type>::dim + dsum<Ts...>::value;
};
```

Then, the return type of `bar()` is `vec<dsum<T,Ts...>::value>`.

A fully working example is here: [http://liveworkspace.org/code/nZJYu$11](http://liveworkspace.org/code/nZJYu%2411)

Not exactly simple, but might be worth it if you really have extremely many different combinations of arguments.

Comment: @MvG I've modified the "full working example". My `bar` implementation was wrong in the first version.